# UIViewController aligment on UIKIt

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm making an app where I need to show different alerts, so I created a custom UIAlertController to be able to modify the controller and show different things.

The problem is that when the alert is displayed it is shown up to the top of the controller, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
final class AlertController: UIAlertController {

    //MARK: - Propeties
    private let config: AlertConfig
    private let style: UIAlertController.Style?

    override var preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style {
        return style ?? .alert
    }
    
    //MARK: - SubViews
    
    
    //MARK: - Init
    init(config: AlertConfig, style: UIAlertController.Style? = nil) {
        self.config = config
        self.style = style
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = nil
        message = config.message
        addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel))
    }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation for `UIAlertController`: *"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and doesn’t support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*.

Comment: Having said that, your biggest issue is that your custom `init` is not calling the correct `super.init`. Call the one provided by `UIAlertController`.